# How to add all the elements of an array to another?

Tags: javascript

I want to add all the elements of one array to another. `Array.prototype.concat` does something similar, but it returns a new array; I want to keep a reference to the same array. What's the most efficient (i.e. performant) way to do this?

Comment: Something like `array1 = array1.concat(array2);` ?

Comment: @tewathia I don't want to lose my reference to the original array. With `concat`, I'm no longer dealing with the same array—I get a new array reference.

Comment: Yes, but then you are passing the new array to the original array(this is super-slow though, http://jsperf.com/splice-vs-push/5)

Comment: @tewathia This demonstrates the problem: `var arr1 = ['a'], arr2 = ['b'], arr3 = arr1; arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2); console.log(arr1 === arr3) // false;`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(dest, source);
```

http://jsperf.com/splice-vs-push/2 leads me to believe this is faster than using `Array.prototype.splice`.

Comment: NO. `concat` and `push` are for different purposes.

Comment: Did you... ask... and answer... your question within 60 seconds? lol

Comment: @NicholasHazel I answered at the same time I asked. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/ http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Don't you mean `dest.push.apply(dest, source)`? Otherwise you are calling `.push` without any arguments.